# Последовательный поиск по столбцам в dataFrame pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть сводный список спортсменов, выступающих в разных видах программ (столбцы "категория")

```
Город   Фамилия категория1  категория2  категория3
Москва  Иванов      "*"     
Киров   Петров                  "*" 
Псков   Сидоров                             "*"
```

*заключил ЗВЕЗДОЧКУ в скобки, иначе текст курсивом*

Я хочу создать для каждой категории свой словарь. Количество категорий не известно, для этого мне нужен конструктор имен колонок?

Вот мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
sheet1 = pd.read_excel('./СводныеСписки_Первенство.xlsx') #Читаю первый раз файл чтобы вытащить количество столбцов,

cols2skip = [4, 5, 6, 7] #список пропускаемых, при чтении, колонок
cols = [i for i in range(len(sheet1.columns)-2) if i not in cols2skip] #список имен колонок
k = []
for z in range(1, len(sheet1.columns)-5):
    k.append('a'+ str(z))
sheet = pd.read_excel('./СводныеСписки_Первенство.xlsx', usecols=cols, names=k)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=sheet.columns) #создаю пустой фрейм с колонками, как у sheet

#Пытаюсь создать функцию, проходящую по каждому столбцу категорий и создающую словарь для каждого такого прохода
def creatTabs():
    #Создаем конструктор имя столбца для поиска по этому столбцу. Вот ту проблема, я не знаю как это сделать
    for z in range(4, len(sheet1.columns)):
        numberOfColunm = k[z] #Присваиваю переменной numberOfColunm элемент списка k с индексом z
        iterSheetColumn = "sheet."+culumnValue #Не знаю, как правильно создать ссылку на колонку
        dict(numberOfColunm) = {}  # Создаем пустой словарь для каждой категории. Словарь для списка участников. Возможно ли в названии словаря добавить numberOfColunm?
        lst = list(sheet.index[iterSheetColumn == '*'])

        #Типа я правильно составил конструктор имени колонки и начинаю парсить колонки
        for i in range(len(sheet.index[iterSheetColumn == '*'])):
            df1.loc[sheet.index[lst[i]]] = sheet.iloc[lst[i]]
            #Определяю ключ и значение для словоря dict
            key = str(sheet.loc[lst[i], 'a2'] + ' - ' + sheet.loc[lst[i], 'a1'])
            value = str(sheet.loc[lst[i], 'a2'])
            dict[key] = value #записываю в словарь пару при каждой итерации цикла
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить правильную конструкцию

Comment: Можете показать в вопросе как должен выглядеть результат?

Comment: dict_a3 = {'Иванов - Москва': 'Иванов'}
dict_a4 = {'Петров - Киров': 'Петров'}
dict_a5 = {'Сидоров - Псков': 'Сидоров'}

Comment: Это если бы я запустил программу по фрейму из примера. а вообще в каждом словаре может быть по 30 человек

Comment: название категории никак в результате не фигурирует?

Comment: Вообще, в реальной таблицу название категории указано аж в 3 ячейках одного столбца. Возраст, вид соревнования и пол. Для этой функции, скорее всего я не буду использовать имя категории, ну или это будет позже, когда пойму, что с этим делать

Comment: Было бы проще если бы вы сразу показали в вопросе какой результат вы в итоге хотите получить (вместо промежуточного). В вопросе вы пишете, что хотите получить списки, а в примере результата показываете словари??

Comment: Максим,  вы правы,  я исправлю в вопросе слово "список" на "словарь"

Comment: И всё же непонятно в чём смысл. Наверняка опять проблема XY или как её там. Конечный смысл этого словаря какой?

Comment: ОХ!! Ну поехали! Я пишу программу табло на соревнования по карате. Было бы хорошо, что бы на табло помимо результатов ещё и ФИО было. Вручную вводить - это плохо. Есть и риск опечаток при вводе. Так вот. У нас есть некий шаблон сводного списка всех участников. Я хочу обрабатывать этот файл, и на экране оператора ввода будет возможность выбрать: 1.Вид соревнований; 2.Пол; 3.Возраст. После этой фильтрации оператору ввода будет доступен список (словари, о которых я пишу в вопросе). Оператор выбирает позицию из списка и она отображается на табло для зрителей

Comment: А зачем в ваших результирующих словарях фамилия повторяется дважды -  в ключе и в значении. Боюсь, что опять недопонимание имеет место. Потому как все, что есть в ваших словарях -  на самом деле список спортсменов, выступающих в той или иной категории. Ну, хотите его город отображать, то, например  - категория1 = {'Иванов': 'Москва','Семечкин':'Задрюпинск'}, категория2= {'Петров':' Киров''}, категория3 = {'Сидоров': 'Псков','Семечкин':'Задрюпинск','Васечкин':'Бобруйск'} Не к такому-ли виду вы на самом деле хотите придти?

Comment: @passant да, Вы правы! При том, что я вообще буду на одном экране показывать ключ (ФИО) и значение(регион), а на другом только Фамилии (и возможно первую букву имя) и Регион

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путем длинных  и сложных выяснений кажется пришли к пониманию того, чего же возжелал ТС.
Мне кажется вот этот скрипт решает проблему:

```
import pandas as pd
idf=pd.DataFrame({'Город':['Москва','Киров','Псков','Задрюпинск','Бобриково'],
             'Фамилия':['Иванов','Петров','Сидоров','Семечкин','Ван Дам'],
             'категория1':['*','','','*',''],
             'категория2':['','*','','',''],
             'категория3':['','','*','*','*']})
kat_name=set(df.columns)-set(['Город','Фамилия'])
df_list=[]
df_names=[]
for k_n in kat_name:
    df1=df.loc[df[k_n]=='*',['Фамилия','Город']]
    df_dict = dict(zip(df1.Фамилия, df1.Город))
    df_names.append(k_n)
    df_list.append(df_dict)

print (df_list)
print (df_names)
```

Результат:

```
[{'Иванов': 'Москва', 'Семечкин': 'Задрюпинск'}, 
 {'Сидоров': 'Псков', 'Семечкин': 'Задрюпинск', 'Ван Дам': 'Бобриково'}, 
 {'Петров': 'Киров'}]
['категория1', 'категория3', 'категория2']
```

Расписал крайне подробно, что-бы легче было модифицировать. В результате вы получаете два списка. В первом - ваши искомые словари, во втором - категории. Не знаю, надо-ли и как их вам надо объединять, но думаю, это не составит уже сложности

Comment: Мне ведь не списки всех участников нужны, это у меня есть. мне нужны списки участников в категории

Comment: А вы код смотрели?? Во-первых, вы просили словари. А во вторых, каждый их словарей и есть список участников в соответствующих категориях. Первый список -  в катетгория1, второй  -  категори3, третий в категория2. Что не так?

Comment: МИЛЛИОН раз извиняюсь! Я не очень хорошо читаю структуру dataFrame, запутался

Comment: @dutik Ну так оно или нет? Если оно -  рад, что помог. Если нет -  давайте разбираться дальше.

Comment: Да я бы хотел сам попробовать разобраться. Ваш код я адаптировал под свою программу. В итоге я получаю, как вы и говорите, список со всеми словарями. Я бы хотел чтобы словари шли друг за другом в той же последовательности категорий, что задана в dataFrame. Для этого я множество ```kat_name``` преобразовываю в отсортированный список и по нему итерируюсь. Дальше, имя такой большой список словарей я могу вызывать нужный мне элемент, преобразовывать его в виде выпадающего списка для выбора пользователя. Весь код работает не очень быстро. для Frame 320*40 компьютеру нужно несколько секунд

Comment: Возможно, у меня появятся ещё вопросы чуть-чуть позже. Но с текущим вопросом вы мне очень сильно помогли!!! Я про то, что можно использовать множестве при переборе столбцов не догадался и вряд ли бы вообще к этому пришёл. Я пытался генерировать имена столбцов... Дуралей